# How to Disable Shiny bs4Dash Dashboard controlbar (Right Sidebar)

Tags: r, shiny, dashboard, bs4dash

What is the parameter to control the right side bar on a Shiny bs4Dash dashboard. My reading of the dashboardControlbar function at https://rinterface.github.io/bs4Dash/articles/step-by-step.html, which I understand to be the sidebar to the right of the page, is to set `disable = T`, in a similar way to how the `dashboardSidebar(disable = T)` controls the appearance sidebar to the left.

I have set `controlbar = dashboardControlbar(disable = T)` however on the Shiny App below and the right sidebar still opens when pressing the button at the top. Thanks for any suggestions in advance.

Edit (in response to dashboardHeader comment ):
This question is in reference to bs4Dash V2.0.0 available via github.
https://github.com/RinteRface/bs4Dash
Please note that the github page also recommends github versions of htmltools and shiny.

```
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)


ui = dashboardPage(
  header = dashboardHeader(),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
    disable = T
    ),
  body = dashboardBody(),
  controlbar = dashboardControlbar(
    disable = T
  ),
  title = ""
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: After running your code I get `unused argument (header = dashboardHeader())`. From which package are you using `dashboardPage` function? I can't see `header` argument in `bs4Dash::dashboardPage`

Comment: I am assuming that the unused argument is because I am using bs4Dash V2.0.0. I updated the question. Thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove controlbar argument to disable it.

```
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)


ui = dashboardPage(
  header = dashboardHeader(),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
    disable = T
  ),
  body = dashboardBody(),
  title = ""
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Oh of course. A simple workaround. That worked. Thnx